# Very confusing, consistent Hibernate lookup issue?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

We have a Spring webapp backed by Hibernate for storage. Recently, we've been noticing problems when performing a lookup using one of our Hibernate storage objects. This is the stack trace:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: object already exists: TABLES"; SQL statement:
SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME=? [50000-128]
        at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:110)
        at org.h2.message.Message.convert(Message.java:287)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:256)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:417)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:378)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1074)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.getQueryTimeout(JdbcConnection.java:679)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.getQueryTimeout(JdbcStatement.java:547)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:299)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:770)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at com.ourapp.hibernate.HibernateDao.lookup(HibernateDao.java:173)
```

I'm having trouble determining exactly what the problem is - is SQL attempting to insert a TABLES object?

Our HibernateDao.lookup() method, line 173:

```
172: Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityClazz.getName() + " as entity where entity." + field + "='" + value + "'");
173: return query.list();
```

This always seems to happen with the same HibernateDao instance (for a Users table, esentially), and is triggered by the same action each time, but we can't seem to determine what the actual problem is.

Comment: try running the generated sql manually and see what s happening

Comment: are parameters coming from web ? can you check to see what is the value of field and value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recent version of H2. You are using a relatively old version (version 1.2.128 from 2010-01-30). I'm quite sure either you will get a better error message, or the problem will go away.

Comment: We're actually using version 1.3.164, what made you think we're using an older version?

Comment: The build number is included in the exception error code. Your error code is [50000-128], so the build number is 128. Build number 128 is version 1.2.128.

Comment: You're right Thomas, Hibernate was including the H2 dependency and we didn't realize it. We have upgraded to the latest version of Hibernate, are tackling a few other hurdles, but will be back with additional information once the upgrade is complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Hibernate parameter and SQL logging.  For example, in the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE #******this is the most important piece
log4j.appender.hibernate=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.hibernate.File=/blah/logs/hibernate.log
log4j.appender.hibernate.MaxFileSize=10024KB
log4j.appender.hibernate.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: In hibernate.properties I have the show_sql parameter enabled, and I also have a DATABASE_NAME.trace.db file alongside by h2.db file that contains the stack trace in my original question - will the above changes add any additional information, or just append it to an additional location?

Comment: Another thought is that hibernate often (always?) does a flush when you run a select.  If you are modifying objects of this type (entityClazz) inside the same transaction or the entity in question does not have equals() implemented, hibernate might be trying to write out the object.

Comment: Depends on how you have want log4j configured.  The example is set up so that hibernate logs to its own file.  You could also log the .type stuff to yet another file if you wanted.